# Php Location("some other page")

Tags: php, location, sleep

I'm new to PHP and this is something that I don't know how to do, even though I have been searching it.

I know that redirecting can be made with `Location("some page")`. I also read that this works just if there is nothing displayed to user.

What I want to do is:

Display a message to user. `echo "message.redirecting...."`

Wait for 2 seconds `sleep(2);`

Then redirect `Location("some page");`

Any ideas?

Andrew

**This is part of an assignment and javascript is not allowed. Only PHP.**

Comment: looks like JavaScript would be a better choice

Comment: I know, but Php is mandatory and no JavaScript is allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a meta refresh, which is just a html meta tag placed inside the `<head>` of your page. Like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://newurl.com/">
```

This will redirect the page to the `http://newurl.com` after 2 seconds.

Comment: Works only if META REFRESH is not disabled in browser settings.

Comment: It's a pretty old and ugly trick, kinda weird your professor wants that, but there's no other sane way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 4):

Do not do it this way.
It's VERY bad usability.
And there is not much sense in saying "redirecting".
That's legacy of ancient ages of raw HTML sites. No good site using such redirects these days.

Redirect with no messages.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't do that. header() calls, such as header('Location: '); rely on http headers, which have to be sent before any output is sent to the client.

Comment: in fact, he can. But he shouldn't anyway

Comment: How can he send headers after producing output?

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend using a  Javascript Redirect if you want a message displayed to the users.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function delayer(){
    window.location = "../javascriptredirect.php"
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 5000)">
<h2>Prepare to be redirected!</h2>
<p>This page is a time delay redirect, please update your bookmarks to our new 
location!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

or you can do a php redirect like this:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
?>
```